# Expo: Building with EAS results in an app bundle where fetch does not work. It works in Expo-Go

Tags: node.js, expo

While everything works fine on Expo-Go and Expo SDK 49, building the bundle with

> eas build -p android

Results in a bundle that I cannot use since my login route can't get anything from the server. The error is:

> TypeError: Network request failed

This only happened due to updating Expo SDK from 46 to 49, it was working fine before.
I have tried to update every possible library to the latest version since this started happening and I even started removing libraries that the package manager says have unmet dependencies just to test this but it still happens.

I also read that maybe babel was not configured correctly. I never configured anything.

The build finishes successfully, the issue is that I can't login. I am using the same server for development and production, through HTTP.

I also tried to delete yarn and npm cache, use yarn or npm for installing the packages (I don't know if that makes any difference) and even moved to another computer.

I was using node v18 before but the EAS logs showed it was using node v16 so now I am using it too to try to make the problem appear in Expo-Go but it doesn't.

I had to add some parameters to metro.config.js when updating i18n-js, so I am adding it to my package.json, babel.config.js (I am using Expo managed) and my [stderr] lines of gradle logs (it does not fit entirelly on this post), I don't know if it helps finding the problem.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my_app_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "expo": "^49.0.8",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.5.3",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-localization": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "i18n-js": "^4.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo']
  };
};
```

metro.config.js:

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

// module.exports = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = (async () => {
   const {
      resolver: { sourceExts },
   } = config;

   return {
      ...config,
      resolver: {
         ...config.resolver,
         sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'mjs'],
      },
   };
})();
```

gradle logs:

```
> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:2728:18: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "__shouldPauseOnThrow"
          typeof DebuggerInternal !== 'undefined' &&
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:11514:7: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in function "logCapturedError"
setTimeout(function () {
      ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:9474:108: warning: the variable "nativeFabricUIManager" was not declared in function "onChange"
...lInstanceHandle ? (from && nativeFabricUIManager.setIsJSResponder(from.sta...
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:10095:21: warning: the variable "clearTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 264#"
    cancelTimeout = clearTimeout;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:13845:
30: warning: the variable "__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__" was not declared in anonymous function " 264#"
  if ("undefined" !== typeof __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:15730:5: warning: the variable "setImmediate" was not declared in function "handleResolved"
    setImmediate(function () {
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19906:12: warning: the variable "fetch" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"
    fetch: fetch,
           ^~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19907:14: warning: the variable "Headers" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"
    Headers: Headers,
             ^~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19908:14: warning: the variable "Request" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"
    Request: Request,
             ^~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19909:15: warning: the variable "Response" was not declared in anonymous function " 499#"
    Response: Response
              ^~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20066:24: warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "readBlobAsArrayBuffer"
      var reader = new FileReader();
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20117:36: warning: the variable "Blob" was not declared in anonymous function " 510#"
        } else if (support.blob && Blob.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
                                   ^~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20119:40: warning: the variable "FormData" was not declared in anonymous function " 510#"
        } else if (support.formData && FormData.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
                                       ^~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20121:44: warning: the variable "URLSearchParams" was not declared in anonymous function " 510#"
...e if (support.searchParams && URLSearchParams.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body...
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20240:26:
warning: the variable "AbortController" was not declared in anonymous function " 516#"
          var ctrl = new AbortController();
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:20373:23: warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 520#"
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19919:71: warning: the variable "self" was not declared in anonymous function " 502#"
...undefined' && globalThis || typeof self !== 'undefined' && self ||
                                      ^~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:24796:27: warning: the variable "performance" was not declared in anonymous function " 711#"
  if ("object" === typeof performance && "function" === typeof performance.no...
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:24819:26: warning: the variable "navigator" was not declared in anonymous function " 711#"
  "undefined" !== typeof navigator && undefined !== navigator.scheduling && u...
                         ^~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:24929:37: warning: the variable "MessageChannel" was not declared in anonymous function " 711#"
  };else if ("undefined" !== typeof MessageChannel) {
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:24944:34: warning: the variable "nativeRuntimeScheduler" was not declared in anonymous function " 711#"
... = "undefined" !== typeof nativeRuntimeScheduler ? nativeRuntimeScheduler....
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:36964:34: warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "start 9#"
...    this._animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.onUpdate.bind(this));
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:90654:9: warning: the property "alignItems" was set multiple times in the object definition.
        alignItems: 'center',
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:90652:9: note: The first definition was here.
        alignItems: 'center',
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:106933:13: warning: the property "alignItems" was set multiple times in the object definition.
            alignItems: 'center',
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:106931:13: note: The first definition was here.
            alignItems: 'center',
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:106961:13: warning: the property "alignItems" was set multiple times in the object definition.
            alignItems: 'center',
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:106959:13: note: The first definition was here.
            alignItems: 'center',
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Task :react-native-svg:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-svg/android/src/main/java/com/horcrux/svg/VirtualView.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> Task :expo-secure-store:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-secure-store/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/securestore/SecureStoreModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you. I resolved it by adding [`usesCleartextTraffic`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) in the [build properties](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/).

Below is the step of how I solved it:

1. Install build properties lib:

`npx expo install expo-build-properties`

2. Add the below snippet to `app.json`:

```json
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "usesCleartextTraffic": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
```

You can reference this link https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/24403#issuecomment-1733872085

Comment: I have ended up downgrading expo to version 48 and the issue did not manifest anymore, but at least next time this happens when I eventually need to upgrade the expo version, I know what to try next. Thanks so much! I will accept this as the right answer once I try it.